# How to remove entry from $PATH on mac

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, path-variables

I was trying to install Sencha Touch SDK tools 2.0.0 but could not run it properly. It created an entry in the $PATH variable. 
Later I deleted the sencha sdk tools folder but didn't realize that the path variable is still there.

When i did `echo $PATH` I got -

`/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin`

I searched on how to remove variables from $PATH and followed these steps :

1. Gave the command `PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin"`
2. Did `echo $PATH` which showed `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin`
3. gave the command `export PATH`
4. Closed terminal and reopened it. Gave the command `echo $PATH`. This time I got 
   `/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin`

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you're doing is valid for the current session (limited to the terminal that you're working in).  You need to persist those changes.  Consider adding commands in steps 1-3 above to your `${HOME}/.bashrc`.

Comment: i'm sorry, i didn't quite get what you are saying. Where should I add the ${HOME}\.bashhrc command?

Comment: and I was aware of the commands being valid for the current terminal session. Thats why i thought "export" would work

Comment: Add the commands in steps 1 & 3 to the file `${HOME}/.bashrc` (at the end of the file).  Open a new terminal and execute `echo $PATH`.

Comment: Simply `export VARIABLE=VALUE` wouldn't persist `VARIABLE` for all sessions.  You need to say that in a startup file, e.g. `${HOME}/.bashrc` or `/etc/profile` (if the changes are intended for all users on the system).

Comment: I opened the file using `nano ~\.bashrc`..it already had `export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3:$PATH` there. Also, when i try to edit and save I'm getting Permission denied.

Comment: adding in bash_profile helped me remove it from PATH variable. I opened it using `sudo nano ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: for me it's `${HOME}/.zshrc` file

Answer (score 226):

1. `echo $PATH` and copy it's value
2. `export PATH=""`
3. `export PATH="/path/you/want/to/keep"`

Comment: Also note that after running `export PATH=""` you might see errors such as:
-bash: tail: No such file or directory
-bash: sed: No such file or directory

That is expected.

Comment: `export PATH=""` is throwing error as `zsh: bad assignment`

Comment: @Pawan any chance you missed have whitespace between the equal signs? i.e: this will show that error, `export PATH =""`

Comment: I tried it and made sure the white space is there. But still I'm getting  bad assignment error

Comment: Is there a way to delete just one PATH entry? Deleting the whole thing seems scary. Do you even need step 2, setting it to ""? Can you put the whole PATH in step 3 without even doing step 2?

Answer (score 41):

Check the following files:

```
/etc/bashrc
/etc/profile
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
~/.profile
~/.MacOSX/environment.plist
```

Some of these files may not exist, but they're the most likely ones to contain `$PATH` definitions.

Comment: ~/.profile returned "no such file" and all others returned "permission denied"

Comment: You need superuser permissions for editing files in `/etc`. You should be able to at least read all of the files, though (provided they do exist). What are the permissions on the files? (`ls -el filename`)

Comment: whats the difference between bashrc in the /etc directory and the bashrc in the ~/ directory?

Comment: The one in `/etc` affects all users, the one on your home directory (`~`) only your own user. And the settings in `~/.bashrc` take precedence over the ones in `/etc/bashrc`.

Comment: To me changing in `~/.profile` worked. I'm using MAC `OS X El Capitan`. I think by default, it's taking from `~/.profile`

Comment: Other options: `~/.zshrc` and `~/.zprofile`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers You should also add `/etc/paths` file and `/etc/paths.d` directory to the list.

Answer (score 32):

**On MAC OS X Leopard and higher**

```
cd /etc/paths.d
```

There may be a text file in the above directory that contains the path you are trying to remove.

```
vim textfile //check and see what is in it when you are done looking type :q 
//:q just quits, no saves
```

If its the one you want to remove do this

```
rm textfile //remove it, delete it
```

Here is [a link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/) to a site that has more info on it, even though it illustrates 'adding' the path. However, you may gain some insight.

Answer (score 12):

If you're removing the path for Python 3 specifically, I found it in `~/.zprofile` and `~/.zshrc.`

Answer (score 10):

`$PATH` contains data that is referenced from actual files. Ergo, you should find the file containing the reference you want to delete, and then delete said reference.

Here is a good list to run through progressively [copied from [@Ansgar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15875513/310139) answer with minor updates].

```
/etc/bashrc
/etc/profile
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
~/.profile
~/.MacOSX/environment.plist
/etc/paths
/etc/paths.d/
```

Note that `/etc/paths.d/` is a directory that contains files with path references. For example, inside this directory may be a file called, say, `fancy-app`, and inside this file you'll see an entry like below:

```
/path/to/fancy-app
```

This path will appear in your `$PATH` and you can delete the entry in the file to remove it, or you can delete the file if it has only the one reference you want to remove.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to find the culprit. /etc/paths.d/ had the bad entry. Thanks @BannerMan

Answer (score 4):

Use `sudo pico /etc/paths` inside the terminal window and change the entries to the one you want to remove, then open a new terminal session.

Comment: In the future I advise you to read the body of the question before answering.

Comment: Also remember to look inside `/etc/paths.d/`

Comment: The answer is incomplete and misleading for someone unaware of /etc/paths.d/

Answer (score 0):

when you login, or start a bash shell, environment variables are loaded/configured according to .bashrc, or .bash_profile. Whatever export you are doing, it's valid only for current session. so `export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3:$PATH` this command is getting executed each time you are opening a shell, you can override it, but again that's for the current session only. edit the .bashrc file to suite your need. If it's saying permission denied, perhaps the file is write-protected, a link to some other file (many organisations keep a master .bashrc file and gives each user a link of it to their home dir, you can copy the file instead of link and the start adding content to it)

Answer (score 0):

Close the terminal(End the current session). Open it again.

Answer (score 0):

If the manual `export $PATH` method does not seem to be working after you close the terminal and open again, **definitely check the shell configuration files**.

I found a small script that kept adding some more path in front of the $PATH everytime it was open.
For zsh you can check the `~/.zshrc` file.