# maven doesn't work in git-bash on windows

Tags: maven, git-bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a git-bash installed on windows 10.
Maven command doesn't work.
When running `mvn --version` the output is:

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher

Maven is working in the regular windows command and in the intellij.
Moreover git-bash does recognize the location of maven and gives an accurate answer to `which mvn`
steps I've taken to try to resolve the issue with no success:

- removed the M2_HOME definition which was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33133809/maven-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-codehaus-plexus-classworlds/33190546)
- created a **.bashrc** and **.bash_profile** files with export command similar to `export PATH=/usr/local/apache-maven-3.x.y/bin:$PATH'
- reinstalled MAVEN a couple of times.

my JAVA_HOME is defined as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261`

Comment: The problem seems to be with the location of Java However I couldn't solve it... 
As a workaround I've enabled Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and installed Ubuntu. In the Ubuntu I have installed JDK and Maven. 
all works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For the maven command to work on my machine, I had to add the maven\bin directory which hosts maven executables in my window environment variables.
`C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin`
I had put there M2_HOME and the full apache-maven directory but without success