# Maven error: Could not find or load main class And Unable to Edit System Variables

Tags: java, windows, maven, environment-variables, maven-3

[image: Maven Installed, unable to edit system variables]
I have Maven installed, and it was working fine yesterday, however now it is displaying the infamous ([Maven error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118237/maven-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-codehaus-plexus-classworlds-l/15236910))

```
Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
```

error...

In other solutions, it seems that the system variable needs to be edited from M2_HOME to M3_HOME. Yet, I am unable to edit my system environment variables (also pictured).

Any suggestions for how I can get past this and be able to perform a clean maven installation?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33133809/maven-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-codehaus-plexus-classworlds/33190546#33190546 ?

Comment: Hi Robert, I mentioned this question in the post - whilst it is similar, I was hoping for an answer which doesn't involve changing the system environment variables since I do not have access to them

Comment: There's no such thing as `M3_HOME`.  Just like the `.m2` folder representing your local repository is also used by Maven 3. Just wondering, who or what set the M2_HOME?

Comment: Answering my own question: chocolatey did that, it is something that should be removed. I followed the same steps you did, and it works for me, which makes we wonder: do you have another Maven on your path?

Comment: So I just uninstalled chocolatey by running command prompt as admin, then reinstalled it. All seems to be working now and I didnt have to touch the system environment variables. So I think thats the answer - thank you for your help Robert :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I just uninstalled chocolatey by running command prompt as an administrator, then reinstalled it. For some reason this worked - no idea as to why but that was the solution to the error without having to change system variables.